# Converting a string to float

Tags: php, floating-point

I am struggling with an issue where I have a string value '62.5816993713379' which when trying to convert to a float value gives me a different result.

Please consider the code below:

```
<?php

$str = '62.5816993713379';

echo floatval($str);
```

It returns me **62.581699371338** instead of **62.5816993713379**

Example: http://codepad.org/WKeLwq7h

Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0):

Because there is float-point  cannot represent all the decimal number and it has the range. There are two solutions:

- Keep your value as a string and use [BC Math Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) to do calculation.
- Increase the `ini_set('precision', 18);` and cross finger that it can precisely represent your number that is out of its range previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$str = '62.5816993713379';
echo sprintf ("%.14f", floatval($str));
```

14f is number of location till you want precision